# Cursor Exception: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java

Hi i know are a lot of resolveing for this but i dont really knwo where to modify cursor. So I build an app where user add names (just names) to a db and with this names in another activity choose 2 random names and set them to a textview; All work fine adding and deleting just last name if i delete antoher name it give me this error. I am new to programming and this part with db i dont fully understand. I will put here

this is db
public void addName(NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Util.KEY_NAME, numeBazaDeDate.getNume());

    db.insert(Util.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

public NumeBazaDeDate getNume(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Util.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Util.KEY_ID, Util.KEY_NAME},
            Util.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate = new NumeBazaDeDate();
    numeBazaDeDate.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
here it s giving me error in stacktrace
    numeBazaDeDate.setNume(cursor.getString(1));

    return numeBazaDeDate;
}

public List<NumeBazaDeDate> getAllNames() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<NumeBazaDeDate> numeList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Util.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Util.KEY_ID,
                    Util.KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate = new NumeBazaDeDate();
            numeBazaDeDate.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.KEY_ID))));
            numeBazaDeDate.setNume(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.KEY_NAME)));
            numeList.add(numeBazaDeDate);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return numeList;
}
    public void deleteContact ( int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Util.TABLE_NAME, Util.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
```

this is the usage of db

```
 primuNume = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, db.getAllNames().size() + 1);
                 alDoileNume = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, db.getAllNames().size() + 1);
                while(primuNume==alDoileNume)
                {
                    alDoileNume = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, db.getAllNames().size() + 1);
                }
                iaPrimulNume = db.getNume(primuNume).getNume();
                iaAlDoileaNume1 = db.getNume(alDoileNume).getNume();//
             here it s 125 picolo
                while (iaPrimulNume==iaAlDoileaNume1) {
                    alDoileNume = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, db.getAllNames().size() + 1);

                }
                iaAlDoileaNume1 = db.getNume(alDoileNume).getNume();
                if(numaratoare!=3 &&numaratoare!=7 && numaratoare !=9 ) {
                int randomDinLista1 = random.nextInt(ro.a.size() - numaratoare) + numaratoare;
                String primaEtapaDeInlocuire = ro.a.get(randomDinLista1).replace("yx", iaPrimulNume);
                String aDouaEtapaDeInlocuire = primaEtapaDeInlocuire.replaceAll("xy", iaAlDoileaNume1);
                Collections.swap(ro.a, numaratoare, randomDinLista1);
                intrebari.setText(aDouaEtapaDeInlocuire);
```

and this is part where i notify that i delete an item in recycler view

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            int position;
            position = getAdapterPosition();
            NumeBazaDeDate numeBazaDeDate = itemList.get(position);
            DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(this.deleteButton.getContext());
            dataBaseHandler.deleteContact(numeBazaDeDate.getId());
            itemList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

I know maybe it s easy or something but I don't really understand who it work. With cursors.
thanks for your time

and stacktrace

```
 android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.example.drinkingtime.Treburi.DataBaseHandler.getNume(DataBaseHandler.java:54)
    at com.example.drinkingtime.Picologane.lambda$test$1$Picologane(Picologane.java:125)
    at com.example.drinkingtime.-$$Lambda$Picologane$47FVTf4B72VAKxsVCBbiLrT-Dz0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace and add comment where the line where it's happening is?

Comment: I edit it. Thanks for reply

Comment: Now please point out `Picologane.java:125`, and `DataBaseHandler.java:54` but also check (or make sure) that your database isn't empty as well.

Comment: i put a //comment below every line you mentioned. And my db isn*t empty . to go to that activity need to have at least 2 elements